# Wordpress set featured image of one post to change daily to the featured image from another post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I have a post (post id 8661) that contains a list of recent posts from another post type (wakeup). These (wakeup) posts are added daily. I would like the thumbnail of the main, listing post (8661) to change to the featured image of the most recent (wakeup) post in the list every day.

```
function set_custom_thumbnail( $post_8661, $thumbnail_id ) {
  $post_8661 = get_post(8661);
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wakeup',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 1
  );
  $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ($new_query->have_posts()) {
    while($new_query->have_posts()){
        $new_query->the_post();
        $thumbnail_id = the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        }
      wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return update_post_meta( $post_8661, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id );
}
```

Comment: I see that you have named the variable `$thumbnail_id` If you want to get thumbnail id then use [get_post_thumbnail_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/)

Comment: Your question could use some more clarity.  Why is variable `$post_8661` being passed? Is this always post 8661? Also, why `$thumbnail_id` as a param for your function? How is your function used and called? Is it hooked somewhere?

Comment: @HowardE, yes post 8661 will always be the post that I want to force the featured image on. And I think I explained a bit better how it will be used (question has been edited) but I don't necessarily know if I am hooking it or not. That is where I am stuck. I've been trying to piece together other solutions since I can't find one that exactly fits what I am trying to do.

Comment: You have to hook it somewhere, or put it in a loop, otherwise it won't ever get executed. It sounds like you either need a hook in your template file, or create a custom template in your theme/child-theme whatever you have.

Comment: @HowardE my thought is that this will happen: when I add a new 'wakeup' post and publish it, the featured image associated with post #8661 will change to the new post's uploaded featured image. Where would I hook or loop it to make this execute in that way? It needs to make the change in the database only, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer for you.  This is one way to execute the code on [save post hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/).  Long story short... You need a hook to execute a function, otherwise it's just a function that will never get called.  Suggest you look at [WordPress Hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/)

```
/**
 * Set the post thumbnail for post 8661.
 *
 * @param int    $post_ID (int) Post ID.
 * @param object $post the Post Object.
 * @param bool   $update is it an update or not?
 * @return bool|int
 */
function set_custom_thumbnail( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    update_post_meta( 8661, '_thumbnail_id', get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_ID ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post_wakeup', 'set_custom_thumbnail', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. With the code you provided, any existing featured image of post 8661 is removed but the new one is not added. Does it need to be attached to that post?

Comment: I've updated the answer... Try that.

Comment: Hi Howard, I had already tried using set_post_thumbnail. That one does nothing. I think we're closer with the update_post_meta. I'll keep searching for a solution. Thanks so much.

Comment: Updated answer... removed if ! $update... I tested this, and it works for me.

Comment: Yaaaaaas! It works! Thank you so much for your time on this @HowardE!

Comment: I restored your original question, as it's more better than having my previous answer as a question.